# How to get the GB2312 CODE from the input Chinese Character in Java

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, transfer, gb2312

1) http://php.weather.sina.com.cn/search.php?city=%B1%B1%BE%A9&dpc=1
2) http://php.weather.sina.com.cn/search.php?city=%C9%CF%BA%A3&dpc=1

There is little difference in the two URLs above:`%B1%B1%BE%A9 VS. %C9%CF%BA%A3`, actually, it was `B1B1BEA9 & C9CFBAA3` (according to GB2312, B1B1 represents the Chinese word"`北`", BEA9, "`京`", C9CF，"`上`", BAA3, "`海`")

I'm trying to write a program to get the GB2312 code from the input Character, for example: input:"`北京`", output: B1B1BEA9.

Anybody can help? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String s="北京";
System.out.println(URLEncoder.encode(s,"GB2312"));
```

this will output:

```
%B1%B1%BE%A9
```

are you looking for this?